# [...Array(page)].map((x, i)] Equivalent in Python

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

Can't seem to figure out how to do this in Python. I can do it by making a new array d[] and append values to it and then put it in the array `r["data"]` but I want to do it in one line.

Javascript:

```
const page = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 20) + 20)
const r = {
    id: id,
    data: [...Array(page)].map((x, i) => ({
        time: i * page,
        j: Math.floor(k.x / (page / (i + 1)))
    }))
}
```

Comment: I guess `i` is an index in array?

Comment: Yes, you can ignore the x as well.

Comment: Can you post a sample output?

Comment: Yes it's like this:
{"id":"2","data":[{"time":0,"j":1},{"time":72,"j":2},{"time":144,"j":3},{"time":216,"j":5},{"time":288,"j":6}..]} I don't need the x actually, I don't even know what it prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `arr` is a pyhon list.
Use

```
r = ({
        'id': id, 
        'data': [{
                   'time': i*page, 
                   'j': math.floor(k*x / (page/(i+1)))
                 } 
              for i, x in enumerate(arr)]
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use python list comprehension. You can extend the example below by adding the random number logic.

```
page = 10
r = {
    "id": "something",
    "data": [{"time": i * page, "j": i} for i in range(page)]
}
print(r)
```